# ActiveRecord Joins result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

Doing an ActiveRecord join in RoR seems to work if I look at the generated SQL.
But what I can't figure out is why the result of that SQL isn't returned into the variable.
What I'm doing is:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :readers, :through => :readings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :readings
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :readings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
end

class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reader
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Now, when asking:

```
result = Reading.where(:reader_id => rid, ).joins(:book).select(columns.collect{|c| c[:name]}.join(',')).flatten
```

It shows the correct generated SQL:

```
SELECT readings.id,books.title,books.author,readings.when FROM `readings` INNER JOIN `books` ON `books`.`id` = `readings`.`book_id` WHERE `readings`.`reader_id` = 2
```

BUT: the result variable only contains the values of the Reading record, NOT the fields of the joined table.

What am I missing?

Comment: my dear friend it does't show when you see result variable.    but you can access columns of book.check once

Answer (score 0):

I have made the association changes in question also:-

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :readers, :through => :readings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :readings
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :readings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :readings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
end

class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reader
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Query in this way:-

```
reader = Reader.find(rid)
result = reader.books.pluck(:name).join(',')
```

Comment: Well, maybe I have to add that a choose this form of selecting because I use it in a helper that creates a table out of the results. Passing the helper an array of columns and an array of data which holds the actual data.
So I need all the data in an array.